# Find the area of the small loop of the limacon $r = 1+2\cos(\theta)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, polar-coordinates, area

Find the area of the small loop of the [limacon (graph):](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MSwiZXEiOiIxKzJjb3ModGhldGEpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDA4MGNjIiwidGhldGFtaW4iOiIwIiwidGhldGFtYXgiOiIycGkiLCJ0aGV0YXN0ZXAiOiIuMDEifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDB9XQ--)

$$r = 1+2\cos(\theta)$$

---

**What I tried:**

Set $r=0$ to get [$\theta = 2\pi/3, 4\pi/3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3D1%2B2cos(theta),%200%20%3C%3D%20theta%20%3C%3D%202pi).

Then

$$A = \frac 1 2 \int_{2\pi/3}^{4\pi/3} r^2 d\theta$$

Is that right? **Why do we set $r=0$?**

My book seems to use **symmetry**. The answer given is:

$$A = \int_{2\pi/3}^{\pi} r^2 d\theta$$

so I'm not sure on what that symmetry is based. Is it based on the one above? Or possibly

$$A = \frac 1 2 \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi} r^2 d\theta$$

?

Comment: For future reference, I will recommend you use the $\cos$ instead of the $cos$. You should type in \cos.

Comment: We set $r=0$ to find the boundaries of integration

Comment: Your result is correct. Then the book uses symmetry of $(1+2\cos\theta)^2$ at $\theta=\pi$.

Comment: @Fakemistake Yeah the boundaries but why are those the boundaries? Anyway, I got it. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Fakemistake oh and thanks. Apologies for my ungratefulness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I got it. We set $r=0$ because those give the $\theta$'s where the small loop starts and ends. This can be seen by [retracting the polar graph](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDT_DG_A0JA) based on the Cartesian graph of

$$y = 1+2\cos(x)$$

The small loop begins at $2\pi/3$ and ends at $4\pi/3$.

Comment: I thought it was clear, what the boundaries has to do with the start and endpoint of the small loop. Anyway, did you understand, which symmetry is used? See my comment above!

Comment: @Fakemistake right since pi is in the middle of 2pi/3 and 4pi/3?